Export based on criteria and save as single separate workbooks
I’m looking for some help with a macro. I’ve used a similar macro about 5 years ago and cannot remember what code I used for it.
I’ve got an existing macro report with a front page where performance information can be generated based on criteria such as data ranges and also by sales rep.
What I’m looking to do is create a new macro on a separate tab of the same workbook where I can extract the Sales Figures by Sales Rep into a brand new workbook. Each Sales Rep should have a new workbook created showing only their figures. So, for example, the click of a button would start a macro which would link to a fold, and I’d see something similar to this PaulSales.xslx, JodySales.xslx etc.
Your help would be much appreciated.
Thanks
Below is the front screenshot of the existing Macro where the detail will come from.
Tried a few functions from what I can remember but my memory isnt great
Code update from comment -
Sub RefreshCriteria()
' Refresh all tables on the Criteria sheet
   Dim lo As ListObject
    For Each lo In Worksheets("Criteria(Hide before sending)").ListObjects()
        lo.QueryTable.Refresh
    Next

End Sub
Sub RefreshReport()
' Report SQL and Parameter Declarations
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim FirstDateFrom As Date
    Dim FirstDateTo As Date
    Dim SecondDateFrom As Date
    Dim SecondDateTo As Date
    Dim SalesRep As String
    Dim AllSalesRep As String
    Dim AssignedTo As String
    Dim AllAssignedTo As String
    Dim UserGroup As String
    Dim AllUserGroup As String
    Dim Territory As String
    Dim AllTerritory As String
    Dim Track As String
    Dim AllTrack As String

' Checking for valid dates
    ' First date from
    If IsDate(Worksheets("Parameters").Range("C1").Value) = False Then
        MsgBox "From date is not valid"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        FirstDateFrom = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("C1").Value
    End If
    
    ' First date to
    If IsDate(Worksheets("Parameters").Range("C2").Value) = False Then
        MsgBox "To date is not valid"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        FirstDateTo = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("C2").Value
    End If
    
    ' Second date from
    If IsDate(Worksheets("Parameters").Range("F1").Value) = False Then
        MsgBox "From date is not valid"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        SecondDateFrom = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("F1").Value
    End If
    
    ' Second date to
    If IsDate(Worksheets("Parameters").Range("F2").Value) = False Then
        MsgBox "To date is not valid"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        SecondDateTo = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("F2").Value
    End If


' Get the parameters as set them in the SQL string
    ' Sales rep
    If Sheet1.Shapes("ComboSalesRep").ControlFormat.Value > 0 Then
        SalesRep = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("I3")
        Else
            SalesRep = "0"
    End If
    Select Case Worksheets("Parameters").TickAllSalesRep.Value
        Case True
            AllSalesRep = "1"
        Case Else
            AllSalesRep = "0"
    End Select
    
    ' CRM record assigned to user
    If Sheet1.Shapes("ComboAssignedTo").ControlFormat.Value > 0 Then
        AssignedTo = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("L3")
        Else
            AssignedTo = "0"
    End If
    Select Case Worksheets("Parameters").TickAllAssignedTo.Value
        Case True
            AllAssignedTo = "1"
        Case Else
            AllAssignedTo = "0"
    End Select
    
    ' Assigned to user's user group
    If Sheet1.Shapes("ComboUserGroup").ControlFormat.Value > 0 Then
        UserGroup = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("O2")
        Else
            UserGroup = "0"
    End If
    Select Case Worksheets("Parameters").TickAllUserGroup.Value
        Case True
            AllUserGroup = "1"
        Case Else
            AllUserGroup = "0"
    End Select
    
    ' Customer territory
    If Sheet1.Shapes("ComboTerritory").ControlFormat.Value > 0 Then
        Territory = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("R3")
        Else
            Territory = "0"
    End If
    Select Case Worksheets("Parameters").TickAllTerritory.Value
        Case True
            AllTerritory = "1"
        Case Else
            AllTerritory = "0"
    End Select
    
    ' CRM track
    If Sheet1.Shapes("ComboTrack").ControlFormat.Value > 0 Then
        Track = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("U3")
        Else
            Track = "0"
    End If
    Select Case Worksheets("Parameters").TickAllTrack.Value
        Case True
            AllTrack = "1"
        Case Else
            AllTrack = "0"
    End Select
    
    ' Sets SQL for first date range activities/quotes and refreshes connection
    SQL = FormSQL.ActivitiesSQL.Text
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@DateFrom", Format(FirstDateFrom, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@DateTo", Format(FirstDateTo, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@SalesRep", SalesRep)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllSalesRep", AllSalesRep)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AssignedTo", AssignedTo)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllAssignedTo", AllAssignedTo)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@UserGroup", UserGroup)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllUserGroup", AllUserGroup)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@Territory", Territory)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllTerritory", AllTerritory)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@Track", Track)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllTrack", AllTrack)
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qry_activitiesfirstdate").ODBCConnection
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .CommandText = SQL
        .Refresh
    End With
    
    ' Sets SQL for second date range activities/quotes and refreshes connection
    SQL = FormSQL.ActivitiesSQL.Text
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@DateFrom", Format(SecondDateFrom, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@DateTo", Format(SecondDateTo, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@SalesRep", SalesRep)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllSalesRep", AllSalesRep)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AssignedTo", AssignedTo)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllAssignedTo", AllAssignedTo)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@UserGroup", UserGroup)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllUserGroup", AllUserGroup)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@Territory", Territory)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllTerritory", AllTerritory)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@Track", Track)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllTrack", AllTrack)
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qry_activitiesseconddate").ODBCConnection
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .CommandText = SQL
        .Refresh
    End With
    
    ' Sets SQL for first date range records and refreshes connection
    SQL = FormSQL.RecordsSQL.Text
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@DateFrom", Format(FirstDateFrom, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@DateTo", Format(FirstDateTo, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@SalesRep", SalesRep)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllSalesRep", AllSalesRep)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AssignedTo", AssignedTo)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllAssignedTo", AllAssignedTo)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@UserGroup", UserGroup)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllUserGroup", AllUserGroup)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@Territory", Territory)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllTerritory", AllTerritory)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@Track", Track)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllTrack", AllTrack)
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qry_recordsfirstdate").ODBCConnection
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .CommandText = SQL
        .Refresh
    End With
    
    ' Sets SQL for second date range records and refreshes connection
    SQL = FormSQL.RecordsSQL.Text
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@DateFrom", Format(SecondDateFrom, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@DateTo", Format(SecondDateTo, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@SalesRep", SalesRep)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllSalesRep", AllSalesRep)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AssignedTo", AssignedTo)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllAssignedTo", AllAssignedTo)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@UserGroup", UserGroup)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllUserGroup", AllUserGroup)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@Territory", Territory)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllTerritory", AllTerritory)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@Track", Track)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllTrack", AllTrack)
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qry_recordsseconddate").ODBCConnection
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .CommandText = SQL
        .Refresh
    End With
    
    ' Sets SQL for first date range enquiry records and refreshes connection
    SQL = FormSQL.EnquiriesSQL.Text
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@DateFrom", Format(FirstDateFrom, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@DateTo", Format(FirstDateTo, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@SalesRep", SalesRep)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllSalesRep", AllSalesRep)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AssignedTo", AssignedTo)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllAssignedTo", AllAssignedTo)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@UserGroup", UserGroup)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllUserGroup", AllUserGroup)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@Territory", Territory)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllTerritory", AllTerritory)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@Track", Track)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllTrack", AllTrack)
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qry_enquiriesfirstdate").ODBCConnection
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .CommandText = SQL
        .Refresh
    End With
    
    ' Sets SQL for second date range enquiry records and refreshes connection
    SQL = FormSQL.EnquiriesSQL.Text
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@DateFrom", Format(SecondDateFrom, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@DateTo", Format(SecondDateTo, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@SalesRep", SalesRep)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllSalesRep", AllSalesRep)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AssignedTo", AssignedTo)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllAssignedTo", AllAssignedTo)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@UserGroup", UserGroup)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllUserGroup", AllUserGroup)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@Territory", Territory)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllTerritory", AllTerritory)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@Track", Track)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllTrack", AllTrack)
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qry_enquiriesseconddate").ODBCConnection
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .CommandText = SQL
        .Refresh
    End With
    
    ' Sets SQL for open records and refreshes connection
    SQL = FormSQL.OpenRecordsSQL.Text
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@SalesRep", SalesRep)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllSalesRep", AllSalesRep)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AssignedTo", AssignedTo)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllAssignedTo", AllAssignedTo)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@UserGroup", UserGroup)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllUserGroup", AllUserGroup)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@Territory", Territory)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllTerritory", AllTerritory)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@Track", Track)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@@AllTrack", AllTrack)
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qry_openrecords").ODBCConnection
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .CommandText = SQL
        .Refresh
    End With

' Go to Main report and notify the user
    Dim ReportRunInfo As String
    ReportRunInfo = "Report refreshed: " + Format(Now(), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm") + ". Customer Sales Rep: " + IIf(Worksheets("Parameters").TickAllSalesRep.Value, "All sales reps", Worksheets("Parameters").Range("I2")) + ". Record Assigned To User: " + IIf(Worksheets("Parameters").TickAllAssignedTo.Value, "All assigned to users", Worksheets("Parameters").Range("L2")) + ". User Group: " + IIf(Worksheets("Parameters").TickAllUserGroup.Value, "All user groups", Worksheets("Parameters").Range("O2")) + ". Territory: " + IIf(Worksheets("Parameters").TickAllTerritory.Value, "All territories", Worksheets("Parameters").Range("R2")) + ". Track: " + IIf(Worksheets("Parameters").TickAllTrack.Value, "All tracks", Worksheets("Parameters").Range("U2")) + "."
    
    Worksheets("Completed Activities & Quotes").Range("A3").Value = ReportRunInfo
    Worksheets("Completed Activities & Quotes").Range("A5").Value = "Completed activities between " + Format(FirstDateFrom, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm") + " and " + Format(FirstDateTo, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm") + "."
    Worksheets("Completed Activities & Quotes").Range("E5").Value = "Completed activities between " + Format(SecondDateFrom, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm") + " and " + Format(SecondDateTo, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm") + "."
    
    
    Worksheets("Closed Records").Range("A3").Value = ReportRunInfo
    Worksheets("Closed Records").Range("A5").Value = "Closed records between " + Format(FirstDateFrom, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm") + " and " + Format(FirstDateTo, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm") + "."
    Worksheets("Closed Records").Range("E5").Value = "Closed records between " + Format(SecondDateFrom, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm") + " and " + Format(SecondDateTo, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm") + "."
    
    
    Worksheets("Closed Record Enquiries").Range("A3").Value = ReportRunInfo
    Worksheets("Closed Record Enquiries").Range("A5").Value = "Closed record enquiries between " + Format(FirstDateFrom, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm") + " and " + Format(FirstDateTo, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm") + "."
    Worksheets("Closed Record Enquiries").Range("I5").Value = "Closed record enquiries between " + Format(SecondDateFrom, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm") + " and " + Format(SecondDateTo, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm") + "."
    
    Worksheets("Open Records By Period").Range("A3").Value = ReportRunInfo
    Worksheets("Open Records By Period").Range("A5").Value = "Open records as of " + Format(Now(), "dd/MM/yyyy") + "."
    
    Sheets("Completed Activities & Quotes").Select
    MsgBox "Refresh complete", vbInformation, "59840 - CRM Activity Report"

End Sub
End Sub
Screenshot

Please edit your question and add the code you have tried.

Please use this VBA code to create a Markdown table from your data and edit it into your question.

I've not tried any yet as I cannot remember for the life of me what I used last time. Below is the coding currently in there. My apologies if I'm not providing enough detail.

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
// Get the active cell and worksheet.
let selectedCell = workbook.getActiveCell();
let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
// Set fill color to yellow for the selected cell.
selectedCell.getFormat().getFill().setColor("yellow");
// TODO: Write code or use the Insert action button below.}
Option Explicit
Sub Charter()
Dim my_range    As Range
Set my_range = Selection
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:= my_range
Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub

Code goes in the question please  - it's unreadable as a comment.  Click the edit link and add the code.

Are you looking for OfficeScripts or VBA solution? Your first snippet is OfficeScripts code.

Your posted code looks like two snips of random unrelated javascript and VBA?

Again my apologies. Excuse my daftness, I didn't realise what I had posted. I've corrected this now.
